How fast does a mole move its claws into soil?
I was watching this video which reports on studies of the force involved when moles dig in soil.
At around 0:30 seconds into the video you can see the mole typically pulls its paws back into the space which has been created by making a tunnel and then thrusts them forwards into the soil before pulling to the side, does anyone have an estimate for the speed at which its thrusts its claws forwards into the soil in the initial part of the digging motion?

Welcome to SE Biology. Questions on this site should be self-contained and not require anyone to go to some other site to watch a video. Please try to rephrase the question so that the video link is suplementary to a full explanation of what you require. Also, provide info on the attempts you have made to answer the question yourself.
